# How to Restart Nodeos Block Producer

Tags: block-producer, nodeos, macos

yesterday I created and launched a single node test net on MacOS. To shut it down I pressed `CTRL + C` and then shut down my computer a while after.

Today I tried to restart the block producer with `nodeos` and got this:

```
[mikeys-iMac:~ mikey$ nodeos
3086500ms thread-0   chain_plugin.cpp:125          plugin_initialize    ]
 initializing chain plugin
3086502ms thread-0   block_log.cpp:120             open                 ]
 Log is nonempty
3086502ms thread-0   block_log.cpp:123             open                 ]
 my->head->block_num(): 1 
3086502ms thread-0   block_log.cpp:129             open                 ]
 Index is nonempty
3086526ms thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:247           plugin_initialize    ]
 configured http to listen on 127.0.0.1:8888
3086526ms thread-0   net_plugin.cpp:2822           plugin_initialize    ]
 Initialize net plugin
3086526ms thread-0   net_plugin.cpp:2843           plugin_initialize    ]
 host: 0.0.0.0 port: 9876 
3086526ms thread-0   net_plugin.cpp:2915           plugin_initialize    ]
 my node_id is c483a327e508ab99d2039b4604ea4e8086dc84d9becd9f373f4df512d8397ad8
3086526ms thread-0   main.cpp:94                   main                 ]
 nodeos version 29c30f10
3086526ms thread-0   main.cpp:95                   main                 ]
 eosio root is /Users/mikey/Library/Application Support
3086527ms thread-0   chain_plugin.cpp:253          plugin_startup       ]
 starting chain in read/write mode
3086527ms thread-0   chain_plugin.cpp:258          plugin_startup       ]
 Blockchain started; head block is #1, genesis timestamp is 2018-03-02T12:00:00.000
3086527ms thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:285           plugin_startup       ]
 start listening for http requests
3086527ms thread-0   net_plugin.cpp:2927           plugin_startup       ]
 starting listener, max clients is 25
3086527ms thread-0   producer_plugin.cpp:381       plugin_startup       ] 
 producer plugin:  plugin_startup() begin
3086527ms thread-0   producer_plugin.cpp:397       plugin_startup       ]
 No producers configured! Starting as a validator
3086527ms thread-0   producer_plugin.cpp:401       plugin_startup       ]
 producer plugin:  plugin_startup() end
```

How do I make it start producing blocks again so that I can continue with the rest of the EOSIO tutorials?

Would also greatly appreciate a short explanation of correct starting / stopping procedures in a development environment. Thank you (:

Comment: Did you try running `nodeos --resync`?

Comment: I tried just then and got a response which included:

`1347966ms thread-0   controller.cpp:1073           startup              ] 
 No head block in fork db, perhaps we need to replay
1347966ms thread-0   controller.cpp:264            initialize_fork_db   ]
  Initializing new blockchain with genesis state                  
1348006ms thread-0   controller.cpp:208            init                 ] unconf_blocknum: 1`

Comment: What about `nodeos --replay` ?

Comment: I got the same thing as the previous comment with a few other lines of code that weren't red and don't sound like they are describing any issues

Comment: `No producers configured!` - Do you have a producer-name set in `config.ini`?

Comment: I was producing blocks yesterday, I'm not sure where  the config.ini file is, where can I find it?

Comment: I tried tryping `nodeos -e -p eosio` and it got it producing blocks again, but is this the solution?

Comment: that's one way, i'll post a more comprehensive answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77757/discussion-between-don-peat-and-mikey-musch).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`No producers configured!` - You are trying to run nodeos without a block producer.

You can set a producer command line with `-p <producername>` in this case `-p eosio`

Alternatively, you can set the producer name in the config file which is generated when you first run nodeos.

> nodeos uses a custom configuration folder. The location of this folder
>   is determined by your system.
>
> Mac OS: ~/Library/Application Support/eosio/nodeos/config
>
> Linux:  ~/.local/share/eosio/nodeos/config
>
> The build seeds this folder with a
>   default genesis.json file and a config.ini file

In `config.ini` you can add the following line to set the producer name to run nodeos without the extra option & argument:

```
 # Enable block production with the testnet producers
 producer-name = eosio
```

See 'Advanced Steps' in [Creating and Launching a Single Node Testnet](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/wiki/Local-Environment#4-creating-and-launching-a-single-node-testnet)

As far as stopping/starting, `CTRL + C` should kill the process allowing you to start it right back up again.  I can recreate the same error in Ubuntu if I *suspend* the process with `CNTRL + Z` and attempt to run nodeos again.